# Verificação de domínios usando RegistroBR e Heroku

Tags: dns, heroku

Estou configurando o DNS do meu domínio no RegistroBR usando o PointDNS (como um add-on do Heroku).

A configuração foi feita seguindo esse artigo: https://medium.com/trainingcenter/dom%C3%ADnio-registrobr-pointdns-heroku-f4e9ea435b04

Tudo funcionou e a minha aplicação está rodando. O problema é que quando tento adicionar o Automated Certificate Management (ACM). Eu não consigo adicionar os domínios **myapp.com.br.herokudns.com** e **www.myapp.com.br.herokudns.com** (fornecidos no dashboard) no RegistroBR e, portanto, esses falham quando o Heroku tenta verificar.

No momento eu utilizo os endereços fornecidos pelo PointDNS (semelhante ao que é mostrado no artigo do Medium).

Quais endereços eu devo utilizar? Tenho que fazer alguma outra configuração no RegistroBR?

Comment: também gostaria de saber mais sobre como configurar registro.br para o heorku com o pointdns... alguém manja disso?

Answer (score -1):

Demorei para entender como resolvia isso e, como consegui, sinto que colocar minha resposta aqui pode ajudar muita gente. Aqui vou tentar ser o mais completo possível fazendo um passo a passo, mas **a resposta direta para a pergunta está no Passo 4**.

### Passo 0: eu preciso do PointDNS?

**Depende**, mas olha... **nos dias atuais muito provavelmente a resposta será sim**. Você pode sim usar o próprio servidor DNS que o registro.br fornece, mas ele não possui suporte para *records* de tipo `ANAME`/`ALIAS`, sendo que o Heroku exige isso para domínios root. Isso significa que, apesar de você poder usar o `www` (ex.: `https://www.meu-dominio.com`), não poderá usar o root do seu domínio (ex.: `https://meu-dominio.com`). Atualmente muitas pessoas não digitam mais o `www` no início e, apesar de alguns navegadores modernos colocarem o prefixo automaticamente, você corre o risco do seu visitante digitar e não conseguir acessar seu site. Por conta disso o serviço DNS do registro.br, apesar se ser bom, não supre todas as necessidades.

### Passo 1: habilitando o add-on do PointDNS

Para configurar corretamente o ACM juntamente com o PointDNS você precisa adicionar esse add-on em pelo menos um dos seus apps. Note que, **não necessariamente você precisa configurar o PointDNS para o app que ele está conectado e pode direcionar subdomínios para outros apps**. Como experiência pessoal, eu tenho o add-on no meu app de produção e também uso-o para configurar o domínio de *staging*.

Para configurar:

- Pela UI: Entre na aba *Resources*; na parte de *add-ons*, pesquise por *PointDNS* no campo de busca e selecione o resultado que tiver o plano *Developer*.
- Pelo CLI: digite o comando: `heroku addons:create pointdns:developer`.

Este plano é gratuito e permite 10 *records* com 10.000 redirecionamentos mensais (mais que o suficiente para um projeto pessoal).

### Passo 2: adicionando um domínio no Heroku

Caso você já não tenha feito isso antes, esse sim você precisará adicionar no app que irá utilizar no Heroku. Para adicionar, utilize:

- Pela UI: Entre na aba *Settings*; na parte de *domains*, clique em *Add domain*. Digite seu domínio e clique em *next*. Copie o DNS target que aparecerá, você precisará dele depois.
- Pelo CLI: digite o comando: `heroku domains:add www.example-domain.com`. Depois, digite o comando `heroku domains` e copie o DNS target que aparecerá, você precisará dele depois.

**Obs. 1:** O DNS target será algo no formato `papagaio-brasileiro-13fqwefrr4r.herokudns.com` ou algo parecido que termine em `.herokudns.com`

**Obs. 2:** Lembre-se que `meu-dominio.com` e `www.meu-dominio.com` são 2 *records* diferentes e, caso queira abranger ambas as grafias dos usuários, você precisará registrar ambos.

### Passo 3: modificando os nameservers do registro.br

Se você ainda não fez isso, sem problemas, façamos agora.

Antes de entrar na sua conta do registro.br, veja a [lista de Nameservers no app do PointDNS](https://app.pointhq.com/nameservers) (você precisará estar logado) e escolha os 3 que possuírem melhor localização (no momento que escrevo eles recomendam 3). Adicione esses 3 escolhidos na lista de *records* com tipo `NS`.

Agora entrando na sua conta do registro.br:

1. Clique no domínio da lista que deseja editar.
2. Na seção de DNS, clique em `Alterar Servidores DNS`.
3. Coloque 1 master e 2 slaves com os 3 nameservers que você escolheu no PointDNS.
4. Salve tudo e, **importante, aguarde por pelo menos 2 horas para que essas mudanças se propaguem**.

### Passo 4: adicionando os DNS targets no PointDNS (válido para qualquer outro serviço de DNS)

Se você tiver usando o PointDNS e já tiver passado pelos **passos 1 e 2**, provavelmente ao acessar a interface você já verá alguns *records* escritos automaticamente. Apesar deles serem válidos para acessar o site, não irão funcionar com o ACM (Gerenciador Automático de Certificados). Para isso você deve utilizar os DNS targets que eu falei que iria precisar no **passo 2**.

1. Para acessar o Dashboard do PointDNS, vá na UI do Heroku, na aba *Resources* e clique no *add-on* do PointDNS.
2. **No Dashboard do PointDNS, clique no lápis para editar o *record* e adicione o respectivo *DNS target* no campo *target/data*, substituindo o que tiver lá.**
3. Você pode adicionar novos *records* para outros apps caso deseje utilizar outro subdomínio do mesmo domínio. Para isso clique em *Add record*, selecione o tipo correto, coloque o subdomínio e o respectivo *DNS target* no campo *target/data*.
4. Uma vez que todas as modificações forem feitas, **aguarde por pelo menos 2 horas para que essas mudanças se propaguem**.

**Obs:** Para domínio *root* (ou seja, sem o `www.` na frente, somente `meu-dominio.com`) você precisa **obrigatoriamente** usar o tipo `ALIAS` ao configurar o *record*. **NÃO UTILIZE O TIPO CNAME PARA DOMÍNIOS ROOT.** Para todos os outros *records* que possuam subdomínio (`www`, `staging`, etc), utilize o tipo `CNAME`.

### Passo 5: ufa... acabou!

Somente **aguarde por pelo menos 2 horas** para que essas mudanças se propaguem. Parece besta, mas eu mesmo errei muito nessa parte. Quando as mudanças estiverem concluídas, o ACM irá automaticamente validar os certificados SSL e você não precisará se preocupar mais com isso.

Answer (score -1):

Uma possibilidade que também resolve é usar o naked domain redirect (http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect), que redireciona http://dominio para http://www.dominio e apontar www.dominio como CNAME para o Heroku. Com isso dá para usar o DNS do Registro.br mesmo.

Mas o PointDNS é um serviço ótimo e mais flexível que o DNS gratuito (incluso) do Registro.br, então enquanto for gratuito o nível de uso que você precisa vale sim utilizar.